# Inconsistent Angular Routing

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have the following route set up in an Angular 1 Application:

```
.state('myConfiguration', {
  parent: '/',
  url: 'myConfiguration',
  resolve: {
    ready: function() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      return new Promise(function() {
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/myConfiguration';
      });
    }
  }
});
```

If I'm on my landing page and click the link which corresponds to this route, I get re-directed back to my landing page. If I instead go to another route first and then click on the link which corresponds to this route, I am taken to the correct location.

Any ideas as to why this may be happening and suggestions on where to begin looking in order to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IE browser does not have support for window.location.origin so please use window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');